# Remove a duplicate Contact from all Journeys in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, duplicate-management

In Marketing Cloud, we had a duplicate contact (some with several email addresses) enter several journeys.  I have deduped the Contact in Salesforce (which was in a Data Extension in Marketing Cloud), and removed the duplicates in Contact Builder in Marketing Cloud, but they continue to receive emails.

How can I be sure that a duplicate Contact is totally removed from All Journeys and stops receiving emails?

Answer (score 1):

In Journey Settings:

[image: Journey Settings]

You have **Contact Entry** which determines if a contact can `re-entry anytime` in a journey, `re-entry after exiting` (after leaving the journey) or no `re-entry` at all.

I think best option the fits your case is `no re-entry`.

Comment: Thanks Natan, that is good to know for future Journeys.  But I need to remove contact(s) from currently running journey(s).

Answer (score 1):

You should leverage the EXIT API for journey builder to remove the contacts from a running journey

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/contactExitRequest.htm

Comment: There has to be a manual way to do it through the U.I. Most email marketers are not developers.

Comment: @BrianOconnell  Reactively there is not a way. You could create an exit criteria/goal before you activate a journey then ensure the subscriber in questions meets that criteria

[https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_exit_criteria.htm&type=5]

[https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_define_goal.htm&type=5]

But with a running journey that does not have these pre-configured the exit API is the only resource

Comment: @brian: for new journeys or versions you should consider EazyEs suggestion. For currently running ones you can use an Exclusion Script in the Email send activities, which can be added to activities in running journeys. For this you need a data extension that holds the Subscriber Keys or email addresses of the deleted contacts. Based on the subscriber key it would look like this: ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("YourDEName", "Subscriberkey", _subscriberkey))> 0

Comment: I think the Best Answer is to find an alternative to Marketing Cloud.